# JavascriptMVC: findAll with static json

Tags: model, javascriptmvc, findall

I've got a interesting situation. I've got a controler with the call

```
            Todo.Models.PersonAddress.findAll({
                personId:personId
            }, this.callback('list'));
```

In the model we've got:

```
findAll: function( params, success, error ){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/person/get-address-json',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: params,
        success: this.callback(['wrapMany',success]),
        error: error
    });
},
```

Theses work just perfect. However I'd like to change my model to bring a JSON string that I already have in my current code.. It'd look like:

```
findAll: function( params, success, error ){

    var source = jQuery.parseJSON($('#address-personData').val());
    var person_addresses = this.wrapMany(source);
    this.callback(person_addresses, success);
}
```

But the callback() doesn't work at all and doesn't give any error ou notice. Could any one help me with that issue? All I want is just bring the same information as the one with $.ajax.

Comment: I found the answer:



    findAll: function( params, success, error ){        
        var source = jQuery.parseJSON($('#address-personData').val());
        var person_addresses = this.wrapMany(source);
        
        if(success){
            success(person_addresses);
        }
    },

Comment: Write your comment as an answer and accept it to indicate your question as solved

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the success method here. Try `success()`;